# C reading in utf characters from file

Tags: c, input, ascii, utf, extended-ascii

```
wchar_t c;     
printf("Please enter file path for the input file\n");
            FILE *file;
            char fileName[100];
            scanf("%s",fileName);
            file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
            if(file == NULL){
                printf("File not found program will now end \n");
                exit(1);
            }
            while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
                putchar(c);
                asciiMessage[i] = c;
                //cypher[i] = c;
                i++;
            }
```

I am taking in a file with input like such Ì|€Á¥öÜ. How would I be able to read these characters into my c program. I have a function to convert ascii values to hex. But with dealing with these characters I get negative values as their input.

-52 
124 
-92 
-63 
-105 
-91 
-10 
-36  These are the values I get when I read them and store them into the array then print them out. The | being an ascii character is 124. While the rest are negative.

Comment: I think those characters belong to extended ASCII characters which mean the ASCII values are greater than 128.  You need a storage that can hold up to 255.  char type won't do. You need unsigned char type.

Answer (score 1):

you should use wchar_t functions: `putwchar(c)` , `getwchar(c)`, `fgetwc(file)`, 
  etc ...

look this [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/)